How to use the internal logger in EF Core for my custom internal services?
Using the method UseLoggerFactory, I'm passing the Debug and Console loggers. I'm also creating my own implementation of IRelationalTypeMappingSource that appends the existing SqlServerRelationalTypeMappingSource with some custom logic.
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // ...

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(logging => logging.AddDebug().AddConsole().SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace));
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory);
        optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IRelationalTypeMappingSource, CustomSqlServerTypeMappingSource>();
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=...");
    }


However, I cannot get the logger to log anything. I tried injecting ILogger<CustomSqlServerTypeMappingSource> or ILoggerFactory but it's not using the same logger factory that I passed on UseLoggerFactory(). I see that the way EF Core implements some of the logging like "EF Core initialized MyDbContext using..." is by using the IDiagnosticsLogger<TCategory> but that doesn't work either. The logger in the IDiagnosticsLogger doesn't have any of the configured loggers that I did in OnConfiguring. I tried inject IDbContextOptions and call FindExtension() and get the logger, but that doesn't work either.
public class CustomSqlServerTypeMappingSource : SqlServerTypeMappingSource
{
    public CustomSqlServerTypeMappingSource(
        TypeMappingSourceDependencies dependencies,
        RelationalTypeMappingSourceDependencies relationalDependencies,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        : base(dependencies, relationalDependencies)
    {
        var diagnostics = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDiagnosticsLogger<DbLoggerCategory.Infrastructure>>();
        diagnostics.Logger.LogInformation("Created custom source!"); // Does not work
    }

How can I get the logger and display logs like this?
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 10.0.0-dev initialized 'MyDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:10.0.0-dev' with options: SensitiveDataLoggingEnabled EngineType=SqlServer 


Have you tried just configuring an ordinary logging and set Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure explicitly to trace level in the config?

You cannot use a configured ILoggerFactory within an IRelationalTypeMappingSource implementation.

The IRelationalTypeMappingSource has a Singleton lifetime, whereas IDiagnosticsLogger has a Scoped lifetime. While it is common to work around this mismatch using IServiceScopeFactory, that approach is not applicable in this context.
The IRelationalTypeMappingSource is created during the options-building phase and relies on a fixed set of services registered by EF Core. As a result, the IServiceProvider available at that stage has a limited set of services, and your ILoggerFactory is not included in that list.

